# How do you include a custom LESS file inside of a child theme?

Tags: magento-2.1, less

I'm starting a new project using Magento 2.1 and I'm a little confused on how LESS compilation works.

I created a child theme using a purchased theme as the parent. Inside my child theme, I added `_custom.less` inside

`app/design/frontend/MYVENDOR/MYTHEMENAME/web/css/` .

I cleared out everything from `pub/static/` and then deployed static content using

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I'm not sure if that's necessary in developer mode, but I'm running it anyways.

I can't figure out if this is compiling and if it is, where it's going. There's a chance that the CSS I've included to change the background-color of body is being overridden by something else, but even if that's the case I can't find the CSS anywhere in the compiled CSS files.

I'm guessing this should be going into styles-m.css, but I'm really not sure. Is there additional configuration I need to do to tell Magento to include _custom.css when it compiles?

Comment: To expand on this a little bit, I went digging around a little bit inside the purchased theme that I created a child of (Ultimo).

Inside app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/web/css/styles-m.less there is a reference to 

`@import '_infortis_theme.less';`

Then, inside _infortis_theme.less there is a reference to 

`@import '_custom.less';`

So unless I'm completely misunderstanding, it seems like app/design/frontend/MYVENDOR/MYCHILDTHEME/web/css/_custom.less should be compiled into styles-m.css...but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Ok, weird. I changed the mode from developer to production and something broke during the process, so I switched it back to developer and took it out of maintenance mode. Now my LESS is being compiled into styles-m.css. I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Base or main less files are located in `/app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/web/css/`, while custom less or "more specific" less files are usually located in `/app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/web/css/source/`

I'm not sure about where Ultimo theme points to `_custom.less`, but you are correct that it is imported from the "main" less files like **styles-m.less** and it "chain-imports" the "more-specific" less files.

Also I noticed that in your comment you said that the styles-m.less is located in `/app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/**base**/web/css/.

If it imports from there, then I presume that the `_custom.less` should also be located in `.../base/web/css` or `.../base/web/css/source` - depending on the import syntax (`@import '_custom.less'` or `@import 'source/_custom.less'`)

When changing less files, you need to clear static files **and** cache to see the effect on your site.

If you're in developer mode, just use the Admin Cache Management buttons **Clear Static Files Cache** and **Flush Magento Cache**.